# Multiple Plot outputs from a function in rmarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I have a function that produces 2 chart objects and I'd like to use this function in an rmarkdown file and knit it so that I get an HTML report. The problem I'm facing is that when I use this function, I get an output that looks something like this:

[image]

Here "Plot1" and "Plot2" are the actual plots that get rendered. What changes to I need to make so that I only get the following?

Plot1
Plot2

Here is the code chunk from my R-markdown file.

````
```{r OverallGRP106_trended_fav, echo=FALSE, fig.align="center", message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, paged.print=TRUE}
trended_fav(psc_surv,"Overall","GRP106")
```
````

The return statement of function "trended_fav" is as follows:

```
return(list(plot(p4), plot(p1)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll be ok if you assign the function's output to a variable and then call up the element of the variable separately, like so:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
trended_fav <- function() {
  p4 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
  p1 <- ggplot(txhousing, aes(year, median)) + geom_point()
  plot_list <- list(p4,p1)
  return(plot_list)
}
a <- trended_fav()
```

## First report

Here it is:

```{r}
a[1]
```

## Second report

This one is even better:

```{r}
a[2]
```
````

Comment: the reason I don't want to take this approach is that I the rmarkdown file I have created these charts ~ 100 times, calling the function separately for each of the 4 plots would just take up a lot of the time. Diven tat my function is able to produce all the 4 plots at once, I'd like the function to be called only once.

Comment: a[1] refers to the first element of a, which was created in the first chunk.

Comment: See here for more suggestions: https://www.tjmahr.com/lists-knitr-secret-weapon/

Comment: See the use of `mdchunk` in this vignette: https://hbiostat.org/R/Hmisc/markov .  This uses a new version of the `Hmisc` package that is in the process of being submitted to `CRAN`.   Code for `mdchunk` is at https://github.com/harrelfe/Hmisc/blob/master/R/html.s